# Custom UIView and becomeFirstResponder

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a custom UIView that implements the `UIKeyInput` protocol and has

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder{ 
    return YES;
}
```

defined in the subclass.  When calling:

```
[customView becomeFirstResponder];
NSLog(@"is first? %i",[customView isFirstResponder]);
```

during a button click, it returns false, **even though** `canBecomeFirstResponder` is properly set and all of the `UIKeyInput` protocol functions are implemented.  What other things could be blocking this view from becoming the first responder?  It lives inside of a scrollView and another custom view if that helps.

**Update:**

I checked to see what the current first responder was with:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView   *firstResponder = [keyWindow performSelector:@selector(firstResponder)];
```

and surprisingly `firstResponder` was `nil`.  So nothing seems to be hogging the events.

Comment: Is something else refusing to give up first responder right now? Like a text field or something with a custom delegate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you override `becomeFirstResponder`?

> Subclasses can override this method to update state or perform some
>   action such as highlighting the selection.

**Followup:**

> Subclasses can override this method to update state or
>   perform some action such as highlighting the selection.
>
> A responder object only becomes the first responder if the current
>   responder can resign first-responder status (canResignFirstResponder)
>   and the new responder can become first responder.
>
> You may call this method to make a responder object such as a view the
>   first responder. However, you should only call it on that view if it
>   is part of a view hierarchy. If the view’s window property holds a
>   UIWindow object, it has been installed in a view hierarchy; if it
>   returns nil, the view is detached from any hierarchy.

Did you verify you meet all of the above conditions?

Comment: I just subclassed it to play around, and indeed the super is returning NO :(

Comment: Thought maybe that was the case.

Comment: I wish I could buy you a beer.  I added it to the view directly after calling "becomeFirstResponder"... it didn't really hit me that I was calling that on a view that had no parent!

Comment: Sweet :) Glad I could be a part of helping your project along! Virtual beer accepted!