# Why won't my custom view become First-Responder, iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I am following the book, iOS Programming Big Nerd Ranch Guide, and I have come to a lesson where I am to create a custom view, HypnosisView. Now, I am suppose to have this view change it's color on shake, but it says I am suppose to make it the First-Responder.

I used,

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
BOOL success = [view becomeFirstResponder];
if (success) {
    NSLog(@"HypnosisView became the first responder"):
} else {
    NSLog(@"Could not become first responder");
}
```

However, whenever I run my app, it always says that it could not become the first responder.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE

I forgot to mention I get this output message.

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom UIView and becomeFirstResponder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438128/custom-uiview-and-becomefirstresponder)

Comment: I looked at that. I'm still confused. I'm new at Objective-C and I don't understand what I'm suppose to do in the override. I did override canBecomeFirstResponder, but maybe I'm suppose to do more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. I figured it out. I needed to put the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

In the CustomView.m file, not my App Delegate file. Easy fix.

Comment: Thanks. Saved me some time. This is not very clear in the documentation.