# Resetting an app via a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, ipad

I have built an app where the user can press a button and get a number of text responses on each tap. After 10 responses, the button runs out of things to say, so I have a reset button placed so that the user can tap it and run the button method again. At this point I am just having trouble figuring out a method to do the reset.

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize billLabel, topLabel, bill;

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[bill setHidden:YES];

}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender
{
[bill setHidden:NO];
static int counter;

if (counter == 0)
{
    billLabel.text = @"text";
}
else if (counter == 1)
{
    billLabel.text = @"text2";
}
else if (counter == 2)
{
    billLabel.text = @"text3";
}
else if (counter == 3)
{
    billLabel.text = @"text4";
}
else if (counter == 4)
{
    billLabel.text = @"text5";
}
else if (counter == 5)
{
    billLabel.text = @"text6";
}
else if (counter == 6)
{
    billLabel.text = @"text7";
}
else if (counter == 7)
{
    billLabel.text = @"text8";
}
else if (counter == 8)
{
    billLabel.text = @"text9";
}
else if (counter == 9)
{
    billLabel.text = @"text10";
}
else if (counter == 10)
{
    billLabel.text = nil;
}

counter += 1;

}

- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender
{

}

@end
```

Comment: Based on what you've presented, nobody knows how you're managing these 10 responses in the first place -- which means any answer one could provide is a pure guess, something SO is really not intended for. I would recommend you edit your question to address what you've done so far to manage these 10 responses so that whatever "reset" happens to mean can be shared with people that might help. In its current form, your question is ripe for people voting to close it for multiple reasons.

Comment: Some sample code on where you are giving the "text responses" and what "reseting" means would help. It is not clear.

Comment: In addition to what mah suggested, remove the first paragraph. It's nice to read how awesome we all are, but it's not really part of the question.

Comment: Do yourself the favor of reading "Objective-C Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide". It contains not only a sample app like the one you work on, but a lot more information for anyone getting his or her feet in this great iOS world. Welcome aboard!

Comment: I've added the implementation with the button method, hopefully this helps clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is a little confusing, I believe I know what you are to do. Make your `int counter` a class level variable first. Be sure to declare it as 0 at that point. Then, in your reset method simply use this code,

> counter = 0;

You may want to then disable the button, but that's up to you.

Comment: it is a bit confusing, I still haven't figured what he is after, but your suggestion is what he is looking for, I guess

Comment: Each time a user presses the button, it returns text via a counter, however after the counter ends, the user will no longer receive text. I am trying to add a reset button so the user can press the button again and receive those same responses.

Comment: why even make a reset button? why not just say when the counter gets set to 11, set it to 0 in your response generation, so then it just infinitely cycles through...

Comment: That's what I was thinking. It's much more intuitive. Anyway, if anyone could help me with a problem I'm having I would really appreciate it. I can't continue on in my lessons until I solve it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691075/why-wont-my-custom-view-become-first-responder-ios

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. Also I tried your idea ColdLogic and that worked well also. Cheers!

Comment: No problem, we're glad to help.